# NumberPicker is not showing in AlertDialog

Tags: android, user-interface, components, android-alertdialog, numberpicker

I'm trying to add a NumberPicker to an AlertDialog, but it does not apper even though there seems to be no error. I'm pretty newbie at Android coding so I assume it's something really stupid that's missing there.

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

        alert.setTitle("Select the value: ");

        NumberPicker np = new NumberPicker(MainActivity.this);
        String[] nums = new String[100];
        for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
               nums[i] = Integer.toString(i);

        np.setMinValue(1);
        np.setMaxValue(nums.length-1);
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        np.setDisplayedValues(nums);
        np.setValue(50);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
          // Do something with value!
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Cancel.
          }
        });

        alert.show();
```

Comment: Also, to get the number chosen, you'll need to either declare `NumberPicker np` as `final` so you can access it from within the `onClick()` method, or add a `NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener` listener to `np`.

Comment: Thank you! For future, I want to add that "OK" button get the chosen number and a date and saves it to SQL database. What would be the easiest method to obtain it from the NumberPicker?

Comment: Declare `final NumberPicker np` when creating it, then inside the `onClick()` for "OK", use `int value = np.getValue()` to get the number chosen.

Comment: Thank you once again! :)

Comment: +1, I had a similar issue, however it seems like you would want your initial value to start at zero, `np.setMinValue(0);` instead of `np.setMinValue(1);` otherwise when you `np.getValue()` it would be off by one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `alert.setView(np);`
 You have to tell alert dialog to set new view.